# Can all the PostgreSQL indexes index anyelement now?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

From the link
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createopclass.html

I read :

> `storage_type`
>
> The data type actually stored in the index. Normally this is the same as the column data type, but some index methods (currently GiST, GIN and BRIN) allow it to be different. The `STORAGE` clause must be omitted unless the index method allows a different type to be used. If the column `data_type` is specified as `anyarray`, the `storage_type` can be declared as `anyelement` to indicate that the index entries are members of the element type belonging to the actual array type that each particular index is created for.

I know GIN could index it, however, I'm curious about if all the indexes, like btree, gist, brin etc. could index anyelement of anyarray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only index access method you can use for indexing arrays is GIN, so there is no point in having this for any other index access method unless you create index support for your own operator classes.